# Why does the python turtle stop moving when I hold the top of the turtle window?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I noticed when I run a python turtle program, the turtle stops moving when I hold the top of the window down with my mouse. I couldn't find anything documenting this problem.

Why is this and how can I stop it from doing that?

I tried making a simple python turtle program and wanted to move the window. I expected nothing much to happen, however the turtle stopped moving and stopped drawing.

I expect it is a tkinter problem but I'm not so sure.

You can replicate it by making by simply making a python turtle progam in which the turtle moves. It stops moving when you hold the window at the top.

[image: x]

I use python 3.11.

Comment: My guess is that when you move the window, the event loop is redrawing it, so it doesn't have time to draw the turtle movement, too.

Comment: That could be the case I guess.